# stop the timer which is executed after button click

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I've a timer, after clicking a `button` I want the timer to begin, and when the `timer` gets `0` I want to stop the timer. I know I can do that with `invalidate()` function, but I can't access the timer here's code

```swift
    var timer = 5 {
        didSet {
            label.text = String(timer)
            
        }
    }
    @IBAction func onClickAnimate(_ sender: Any) {
        let timerCount = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    @objc func updateCounter(){
        if timer > 0 {
            timer -= 1
        }
        if timer == 0 {
            timer = 5
            timerCount.invalidate() // error is here
            }
    }
```

If I decide to create `timerCount` globally I get an error `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003b466a0"`

any solution will be appericated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1** : make a variable

```
var timerCount:Timer!
@IBAction func onClickAnimate(_ sender: Any) {
    timerCount = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
@objc func updateCounter(){
    if timer > 0 {
        timer -= 1
    }
    if timer == 0 {
        timer = 5
        timerCount.invalidate() 
   }
}
```

**Solution 2** :  use block

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timerCount in
    if self.timer > 0 {
        self.timer -= 1
    }
    else
    if self.timer == 0 {
        self.timer = 5
        timerCount.invalidate() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the block is most elegant imo, would do it exactly like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `timerCount` outside the function but inside the class so that you can access it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   let timerCount: Timer = Timer()
}
```

Then, remove `let` keyword.

You can now access your `timerCount`.

Answer (score -1):

Make `Global variable in Class` like:

```
var timerCount = Timer()
```

Boom!!!... Now you can access it.